# magento 2 decrypt value from Javascript

Tags: magento2

I am working with checkout component file (JavaScript) and I don't understand how to decrypt encrypted value in JavaScript. Found that there is no JS file under framework/Encryption module.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please provide encrypted value

Comment: It's not same, every time new values generated after page refresh, because I am using Magento default encryption to encrypt value.

Comment: okay but is it a hash? json? how does it look

Comment: It's Magento default encrypted.